# merge queries in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is there anyway of simplifying (merging) this query I am using with beautifulsoup?

```
    table  = soup.findAll("tr", {'class' : 'table-tempo-row' })
    tablec = soup.findAll("tr", {'class' : 'table-tempo-row-alt' })

    for i in (table + tablec):
        tableb = i.findAll("td")
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in [a list](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments):

```
table = soup.findAll("tr", {'class' : ['table-tempo-row', 'table-tempo-row-alt'] })
```

and BS will match `tr` elements with either class.

For more complex cases, you can pass in a regular expression, or a function (takes the element and returns a boolean).

Comment: This is very neat and helps me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
tablec = soup.findAll("tr", {'class' : ('table-tempo-row-alt' ,'table-tempo-row')})
```